# Getting Python Tkinter Object Type

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am currently working on a program which handles a number of different possible entry widgets in a Python program.

I need some code to be able to determine what type of widget a particular object is, for example `Entry` or `Checkbutton`.

I have tried using the `type(var)` method to no avail (I get the error missing required variable `self`) as well as the `var.__class__` and I am making no progress.

```
for d in dataTypes:
    if isinstance(d, Entry):
        print("Found Entry!")
    elif type(d).__name__ == 'Checkbutton':
        print("Found Checkbox!")
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I can solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the name as a string, you can use the `.winfo_class()` method:

```
for d in dataTypes:
    if d.winfo_class() == 'Entry':
        print("Found Entry!")
    elif d.winfo_class() == 'Checkbutton':
        print("Found Checkbutton!")
```

Or, you could access the `__name__` attribute:

```
for d in dataTypes:
    if d.__name__ == 'Entry':
        print("Found Entry!")
    elif d.__name__ == 'Checkbutton':
        print("Found Checkbutton!")
```

That said, using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is a more common/pythonic approach:

```
for d in dataTypes:
    if isinstance(d, Entry):
        print("Found Entry!")
    elif isinstance(d, Checkbutton):
        print("Found Checkbutton!")
```

Also, your current code is failing because `type(d).__name__` does not return what you think it does:

```
>>> from tkinter import Checkbutton
>>> type(Checkbutton).__name__
'type'
>>>
```

Notice that it returns the name of the type object returned by `type`, not the name of `Checkbutton`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! The first method you suggested returned an error; "invalid positional argument 'self'", however the second method works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help!